# How to match a Drupal path in Apache config

Tags: 8

My D8 site uses the usual convention in .htaccess to rewrite non-file requests to index.php:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
RewriteRule ^(.*) index.php [L]
```

However, if I try to perform a location match in my Apache 2.4 httpd.conf virtualhost, it fails because it seems that REQUEST_URI is set to index.php.

```
<Location /foo/bar>
  #Directives that should fire when accessing /foo/bar but don't
</Location>

<Location /index.php>
  #Directives that do fire when accessing /foo/bar
</Location>
```

Any ideas for getting this to work?  I have tried:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/foo/bar#">
  #Directives that should fire when accessing /foo/bar but don't
</If>

<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/index\.php#">
  #Directives that do fire when accessing /foo/bar
</If>
```

Answer (score 1):

The directive I was trying to insert was `Require all granted`.  I managed to achieve the same effect by proxy-passing requests for /foo/bar to another virtual host running on the same machine, but unreachable from outside.  That 2nd virtual host did not require auth, which achieved the same effect as `Require all granted`.

```
ProxyPass /foo/bar http://example.local/foo/bar
ProxyPassReverse /foo/bar http://example.local/foo/bar
```